# $f(x)=x\sin\pi x$, where does $f'(x)$ vanish at?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=x\sin\pi x$ for all $x>0$.Then for all natural numbers $n$,$f'(x)$ vanishes at ?

Putting $f'(x)=0$ I'm getting $\tan(\pi x)=-\pi x$.What's next? How to solve that equation?

P.S:Well the question only asks for the possible range in which $f'(x)$ vanishes.

The options given are :(More than 1 option can be correct)

a) At an unique point in $(n,n+1/2)$

b)At an unique point in $(n+1/2,n+1)$

c)At an unique point in $(n,n+1)$

d)At two points in $(n,n+1)$

Comment: what is the natural number n?

Comment: Where does $n$ come in?

Comment: @ZTransformer its a MCQ question with options like $f'(x)$ vanishes at an unique point in $(n,n+1/2)$

Comment: Wait i'm updating the options as well

Comment: @ZTransformer now check!

Comment: @HowDoIMath now check

Comment: Draw a graph! {}{}{}

Comment: Notice $Tan(π x)$ is periodic with period 1, and only negative in $(n+1/2,n+1)$.

Comment: awesome @ZTransformer